# Django и css на gunicorn+nginx

Tags: gunicorn, django

Сделал проект на django 1.6, пока работал на тестовом сервере, все было ок. Сейчас загрузил проект на рабочий сервер с помощью Digital Ocean. Использовал образ Ubuntu 14.04 + django и не могу понять, как подключить статику (css, images, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разместите всю свою статику (css, js, картинки, шрифты) в папку staticfiles в корне проекта или в папке static какого-либо приложения.

Разместите всю медиа (загружаемые пользователем файлы) в папке media в корне проекта.

В settings.py укажите следующие настройки:

```
# добавим это чтоб не писать полные пути
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# настроим статику
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)

# И заодно еще медийку
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

В настройках nginx в секцию server добавьте следующие локейшены:

```
location /media {
    alias /full/path/to/you/project/media; # Это полный путь к папке media в корне вашего проекта
    expires max;
}
location /static {
    alias /full/path/to/you/project/static; # Это полный путь к папке static в корне вашего проекта
    expires max;
}
```

Перезапустите nginx.

Выполните команду

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Что будет происходить и для чего это нужно:

collectstatic пробежится по всем папкам, перечисленным в STATICFILES_DIRS, а также по всем папкам static внутри каждого приложения django, указанного в INSTALLED_APPS. Все найденные там файлы он сложит в одну папку, указанную в STATIC_ROOT, то есть в static. Nginx направлен на эту папку и будет раздавать из нее файлы.
Нужно это для хранения статики отдельно в каждом приложении, чтоб оно было независимым и при этом не приходилось на каждый запрос лазить по всем папкам и искать там файлы, как это делает dev-сервер.

С media (если она вам нужна) все немного проще. Django будет складывать туда файлы, а nginx их раздавать.

Answer (score 0):

На своих проектах применяю такой подход, что позволяет достучатся и до /robots.txt /favicon.ico:

```
#settings.py  
DOCUMENT_ROOT = os.getcwd()
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(DOCUMENT_ROOT, '_media/media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(DOCUMENT_ROOT, '_media/static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# nginx
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|txt|css|js)$ {
    root /project_root/_media;
}
```

Comment: Часто вижу такой вариант и завидую доступу к robots и favicon, но меня пугают следующие вещи:

 - Регулярное выражение все таки сложнее прямо заданного локейшена.
 - Часто на сайтах подключают кастомные шрифты, это еще + 4 расширения в ваш список.
 - Плюс еще PDF, плюс еще можно что то забыть.
 - Как быть если, в проекте часть  PDF статичные, а часть генерируются на лету (при этом для генерируемых тоже хотим url с .pdf)